# Identity valuation using smart contracts

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, identity

Hi I'm currently exploring whether it makes sense to build a platform which would use a blockchain to verify a user and the data that they would add to the platform.

Very simple example would be around people's ideas, so if you were to upload a meme for example the meme generator could say memes 1-3 a free to view, 4 has a viewing cost of 0.003 eth and if another user wanted to forward the generated meme the cost would be 0.006 eth.

From an efficiency standpoint would it make sense to build this all in ethereum, build part of it ( verification and smart contract)  into ethereum  whilst the rest would be in a normal database or would the most efficient test case to be to build it using a normal database entirely?

If it doesn't make sense to use the identity capabilities of a blockchain for idea protection and monetisation what are the major flaws in my initial thinking?